# settimeofday function can't change time

Tags: ubuntu, c, time

In Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I write a program using C to change the system time. During the execution of the program, it does output the modified time using commands **date** and **hwclock**. But when the program ends, I type **date** or **hwclock** in console, there is no change in time. I don't know why.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define BILLION 1000000000L

void TimeSet(int year,int month,int day,int hour,int min,int sec)
{
    struct tm tptr;
    struct timeval tv;
    struct timeval now;

    int res;
    gettimeofday(&now, 0);
    printf("now sec=%ld\n", now.tv_sec);

    tptr.tm_year = year - 1900;
    tptr.tm_mon = month - 1;
    tptr.tm_mday = day;
    tptr.tm_hour = hour;
    tptr.tm_min = min;
    tptr.tm_sec = sec;
    tptr.tm_isdst = -1;

    tv.tv_sec = mktime(&tptr);
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    
    printf("set sec=%ld\n", tv.tv_sec);
    res = settimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    if(res != 0){
        printf("Set fail\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("before time set:");
    fflush(stdout);
    system("date");
    system("hwclock");

    TimeSet(2021,11,9,10,0,0);

    printf("after time set:");
    fflush(stdout);
    system("date");
    system("hwclock");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I have found the reason. The Ubuntu have two clocks: Real Time Clock(RTC,or hardware clock) and System Clock(or software clock). When the system power off, RTC will start which powered by battery. When the system start, the system will synchronize the System Clock with RTC. But this may be not accurate, if you have set some time synchronization services like NTP, it will calibrate the offset. Then the system will only use the System Clock as time resource to deal with something, like interrupt.

If your system have NTP or SNTP service, the change don't work. You have to close these services. You can use the commands: `systemctl status ntpd, systemctl status chronyd, systemctl status systemd-timesyncd` to check whether your system have installed these services. I use `timedatectl set-ntp false` to close the NTP service. You must note that the `settimeofday` function can only change the System Clock. The `date` command use the System Clock, and `hwclock` use RTC. This means that `date` command can show the change, but `hwclock` command can't.